# How to add eslint rules to prettier in Vue project on VsCode

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint, prettier

I would like to add rules to my existing formating rules

Actually I'm using a `.vscode/settings.json` file with the following

```
{
 "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true
  },
  "eslint.validate": ["javascript"],
  "vetur.useWorkspaceDependencies": true,
  "vetur.validation.style": false,
  "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.scss": "prettier",
  "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.css": "prettier",
  "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.js": "prettier-eslint",
  "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.html": "prettier",
  "[vue]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "octref.vetur",
  },
  "eslint.format.enable": true
}
```

It works well but let's say i want to add a rule for exemple [vue-script-indent](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/blob/v4.7.1/docs/rules/script-indent.md)

I don't know how to add this rules to my existing config

Comment: Hey Charles! Eslint rules are generally added to the eslint config file or inside the package.json rules array. Most likely you have an .eslintrc file in your project root. That's where you want to add your rule.

Comment: Hey @kottartillsalu !
Thank you for your time. I do have a .eslintrc but i can't say to prettier "use those rules when i format" and i don't know how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `vue/script-indent` (ESLint rule)

From the [`eslint-plugin-vue` docs](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/tree/v4.7.1#rocket-usage):

> Create `.eslintrc.*` file to configure rules. See also: http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring.
>
> Example **.eslintrc.js**:
>
> ```js
> module.exports = {
>   extends: [
>     // add more generic rulesets here, such as:
>     // 'eslint:recommended',
>     'plugin:vue/essential'
>   ],
>   rules: {
>     // override/add rules settings here, such as:
>     // 'vue/no-unused-vars': 'error'
>   }
> }
> ```

So in your `.eslintrc.js`, add the [`script-indent` rule](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/blob/v4.7.1/docs/rules/script-indent.md#rule-details) to the `rules` property. Note the `eslint-plugin-vue` rule names are all prefixed with `vue/`, so use `"vue/script-indent"` in the `rules` property below:

```js
module.exports = {
  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/essential',
  ],
  rules: {
    'vue/script-indent': ['error', 2, {
      baseIndent: 0,
      switchCase: 0,
      ignores: []
    }]
  }
}
```

Finally, ensure you have the [ESLint VS Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) installed to enable formatting from the IDE.

#### Prettier

Your workspace settings point to Prettier, so make sure your Prettier options align with the `vue/script-indent` rule. That is, the [`tabWidth` value in Prettier](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#tab-width) should match the tab width in `vue/script-indent`.

For example, to require a 4-space tab width, create `.prettierrc` in the root of your project with the following JSON:

```json
// .prettierrc
{             
  "tabWidth": 4
}
```

...and update `.eslintrc.js` to match:

```js
// .eslintrc.js
module.exports = {
  rules: {                         
    'vue/script-indent': ['error', 4, {
      baseIndent: 0,
      switchCase: 0,
      ignores: []
    }]
  }
}
```

Also ensure you have the [Prettier VS Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) installed to enable formatting from the IDE.

[image]

Comment: @CharlesLavalard Updated answer with additional steps to configure Prettier